# Why is if (2 < 9 < 3) true?

Tags: c

This was a question in my preparation exam:

```
int val = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
if (x < val < y)
    printf(" true ");
else
    printf(" false ");
```

Why is this true? I tried changing `x` and `val` and it ignored those changes, as long as `y` was larger than `0` (so `1`, `2`, `3`...) the statement was true. So for example: `if (3 < 9 < 2)` will be true.

Answer (score 61):

`( 2 < 9 < 3 )` is evaluated as `( ( 2 < 9 ) < 3)`.
In the first step `2 < 9` is evaluated to be true, which is represented as integer value 1 and results in `((1) < 3)` for the second step.
That is obviously true.

You probably wanted something like `((x < val) && ( val < y))`.

Comment: @AnnZen I feel honored.

Comment: @Yunnosh Thank you. By the way, it's interesting how our scores are the same for this moment :)

Answer (score 5):

The first is check whether x < value. If true, it return 1 so the next is check whether 1 < y.

Answer (score 4):

First you check x and val. If its value is correct, you convert it to 1 and check it with y.

Answer (score 4):

If you build with `-Wall` option using [GCC compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/nE6Ej4W6E) you will get a warning like this:

```
<source>:7:11: warning: comparisons like 'X<=Y<=Z' do not have their mathematical meaning [-Wparentheses]
     if (x < val < y)
```

Detailed explanation of this warning can be found in [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html). The relevant part is as following:

```
-Wparentheses
     ...
    Also warn if a comparison like x<=y<=z appears; this is equivalent to (x<=y ? 1 : 0) <= z, which is a different interpretation from that of ordinary mathematical notation. 
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: Comparisons in C follow the **left to the right** approach. (if all operators are of same priority)

Thus, evaluation of `(2 < 9 < 3)` will be done in 2 steps:

1. step **1**. evaluation of `(2 < 9)`: it is true, thus, integer value=1.
2. step **2**. evaluation of `( (2 < 9) < 3 )` i.e `(1 < 3)`: it is also
   true.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted `(2 < 9) && (9 < 3)`.

In C, usually operators follow left to the right approch(except operators like =, -=, +=, etc.). Operator <, > follows left to the right approch too. So, 2<9<3 in C means `(2 < 9) < 3`. `2 < 9` is 1, so, the value of `2 < 9 < 3` is `1`.

You can fix it with `(2 < 9) && (9 < 3)`.